# 11.2GB text file import MySQL or PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, import

I am out of my depth a bit perhaps but submit this query hoping someone has some experience importing large (11.2GB) tab delimited text file (2.2GB tar.gz file) into either MySQL 5.5.41 or PostgreSQL 9.3.6. Double precision for the fields will be required as it is spatial data (Latitude, Longitude and Elevation).

I have MySQL and PostgreSQL setup on Ubuntu 14.04 using phpMyAdmin and phpPGAdmin to interact with the servers. However I realise that command line interaction will probably be better.

I have read a bit and there seems to be a way to split data for MySQL (SQLDumpSplitter2 - http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/).

Any suggestions or alternative options greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: What happens in MySQL when you use LOAD DATA INFILE directly on that huge file?

Comment: what if to split in multiple files and then load?

Comment: You can take a look also here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37478/index-before-or-after-bulk-load-using-load-infile/37497#37497

Comment: you should never use MySQL if you need GIS. PostGIS is a superior choice.

Answer (score 1):

For **PostgreSQL**, I would recommend using [`pgloader`](http://pgloader.io/index.html).

`pgloader` leaves the rows that it cannot import in a separate text file, so you can take a look at what went wrong, fix the errors, and finish importing the data. `COPY` simply crashed when it encounters a row it didn't expect, which is likely to happen several times for very big files.

`pgloader` can also be set up to load data in parallel, but I'm not sure how much help it would be if you're just loading a single table.

For **MySQL**, the standard `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is as fast as you're going to get (as far as I know). It spits out a `warning` for each row that it cannot import, so you can go back and look at that data later.

Other than that, 11.2 GB isn't too bad. Be sure to remove all existing indexes on the table that you're importing, and recreate the indexes afterwards.

I've imported text files of comparable size into both databases without a problem. Loading data and creating indexes might take a few hours, so just leave it overnight.